# Fix terminal title after SSH remote logging to another machine

Tags: ssh, terminal, window-manager, window-title

right now I am using an one-line perl code to change titles of my terminal bars,

```
print("\e]0;@ARGV\7");
```

but every time after I ssh to another remote machine, the title will be modified by the host (by which I'm not particularly bothered). But after I exit from the connection, the modified title remains. Is there a way to fix this? essentially I want a fixed title for my terminals when operating locally.

I primarily use xfce terminal and terminator under either CentOS or Debian. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Another subtlety is that, rather having all terminals the same name, I would prefer to have the freedom to edit their titles on-the-fly but only forbid SSH session from modifying what I edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about window titles, but I have been trying to have my system do something on terminating a ssh session—actually, after terminating a ssh session. In short: it doesn't work like that. Basically you have three choices:

1. Write a wrapper around ssh, i.e., an executable shell script named `ssh` that takes precedence over `/usr/bin/ssh` in your $PATH which contains the line `exec /usr/bin/ssh $@` somewhere in its middle. This enables you to have your shell do some stuff before and after the effective ssh binary is run, while keeping th eoverhead to a minimum.
2. Write a patch against the SSH sources of your choice to provide you a cleanup hook that executes a shell command passed via commandline or some config-setting. That's what we want.
3. Have `PROMPT_COMMAND` evaluate the output of `history`. Basically a more generic and more ugly approach to 1.

Comment: basically i just wrote a simple script to grab the current title and save it before SSH session, then recover the title afterwards.

Comment: @nye17 Can you post your solution script that you used ?

Comment: I posted my solution script below.  should be a close match what @nye17 did.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341277/112190

Answer (score 12):

Solution: add some functions ~/.bashrc to do something ***after*** ssh and su commands

```
function title()
{
   # change the title of the current window or tab
   echo -ne "\033]0;$*\007"
}

function ssh()
{
   /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
   # revert the window title after the ssh command
   title $USER@$HOST
}

function su()
{
   /bin/su "$@"
   # revert the window title after the su command
   title $USER@$HOST
}
```

Note: restart bash after edits to ~/.bashrc

Example:

```
# title is "user1@boxA"
ssh boxB  # auto changes title while on boxB to "user1@boxB"
exit
# title returns back to "user1@boxA" because of our title call in ssh()
su - user2 # auto changes title while switched user to user2: "user2@boxA"
exit
# title returns back to "user1@boxA" because of our title call in su()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: slightly inaccurate to say `revert` as you do not check to see what it was before ... if you queried and saved the prior value tho ;-)

Comment: If `$HOST` isn't set, use `$HOSTNAME`

Answer (score 4):

Configure your local shell dotfile (e.g. `$PROMPT_COMMAND` in `~/.bashrc`) to set the terminal title appropriately, using the same mechanism.

For example:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '\e]0;bash\7\n'"
```

Comment: 1. prompt_command has nothing to do the title of your terminal window, right? I have prompt_command set up but only for the prompt. 2. I still need a mechanism to remember and activate my local setting after exiting the ssh logging.

Comment: The prompt command simply emits the necessary escape sequence for your terminal to rename its title bar. :)

Comment: but I also want the freedom to rename whatever terminal I want, rather than having every single session the same name. In practice, I basically edit the terminal title manual and hope that terminal to stay having fixed title even after SSH login/logout. Does it make sense?

Comment: So then put the desired title in a variable, and output that.

Comment: If you use this terminal escape sequence to set a null title (e.g., `export PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '\e]0;\7\n'"`), then your terminal emulator can set the window title as it sees fit. When you ssh to a remote host that sets the terminal title, your terminal emulator will show that title, and when you logout, it will revert to using its own title. At least, that's how the macOS Terminal app works.

Comment: This works for me. I am using terminator.

Answer (score 3):

ADD these lines to ~/.bashrc

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"

    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

works well with debian based linuxes

Comment: IT doesn't set the title though...

Comment: It usually works better to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` instead of using `PS1`, since you don’t have to include the `\[ \]` bracketing and it can eliminate some quoting.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers wouldn't work for me when I exit SSH, but got me close.  Adding setw automatic-rename works when I exit remote ssh session so it auto renames and don't have to exit the window anymore to reset.  [Jan. 2018 - Debian 9]

```
ssh() {
tmux rename-window "$*"
command ssh "$@"
tmux setw automatic-rename
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341277/25975 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28520/25975 have been combined for a simple clean solution at https://drone-ah.com/2020/06/25/how-to-terminal-title-after-disconnecting-from-ssh/. It also restores the previous title.

```
function ssh()
{
    # push current title and icon to stack
    echo -ne '\e[22t'
    # Execute ssh as expected
    /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
    # revert the window title after the ssh command
    echo -ne '\e[23t'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to change the terminal variable to vt100 before ssh'ing, e.g. run

```
export TERM=vt100
```

This works because usually initialization scripts look at the terminal variable and only change it title it it's xterm. You lose alternate screens, colors and maybe some other fancy features you may or may not appreciate.

If you want to keep the local terminal as xterm, alias ssh to change the terminal variable on the fly, like

```
alias ssh='TERM=vt100 /usr/bin/ssh'
```

Comment: it changes the way things are displayed. colours are not shown

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding this to my PS1 in my .bashrc file.

```
\[\e]2;\u@\H:\w\a\]
```

Therefore the whole line looks like this(I've customized my PS!:

```
export PS1='\[\e]2;\u@\H:\w\a\]\n($LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME) \t\n[$PWD]: '
```

I hope that helps others.

Comment: If you use this terminal escape sequence to set a null title (e.g., `export PS1='\[\033]0;\007\]\h:\W \u\$ '`), then your terminal emulator can set the window title as it sees fit. When you ssh to a remote host that sets the terminal title, your terminal emulator will show that, and when you logout, it will revert to using its own title. At least, that's how the macOS Terminal app works.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote server is Debian, put the below code at end of `~/.bashrc`

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}: ${PWD}\007"'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might  be not exactly the most direct approach, but I use remote command execution in order to execute the command remotely on request in some scenarios, but to stay in my former terminal session where applicable like this

```
ssh root@server 'tail -f /var/log/someApp/appLog.log'
```

that way my original non-ssh title stays in place, intact

Answer (score 0):

I used this custom function in my `.bashrc`

```
function s(){
  ssh -t $1 "echo -en '\033]0;'"$1"'\a';bash"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).