# SSH LocalCommand on exit

Tags: bash, ssh, osx

In `~/.ssh/config` you can use the `LocalCommand` directive to execute a local command whenever you connect to a remote machine via SSH. But how do I execute a command when I *exit* an SSH connection? It seems that *.bashrc/.bash_profile* files are not sourced when connection ends or is closed.

Comment: This question is closely related to
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40830/fix-terminal-title-after-ssh-remote-logging-to-another-machine/40871#40871

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not specified in the question if you want this executed on the local or remote machine. It's also not specified which shell is present on either machine, so I'm assuming `bash` for both.

If you want to execute it on the remote machine, look at `~/.bash_logout`, which is executed when a login shell logs out gracefully. From `man bash`:

> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file `~/.bash_logout`, if it exists.

You can do a test in `~/.bash_logout` to check if the shell being logged out of is an SSH session, something like the following should work:

```
if [[ $SSH_CLIENT || $SSH_CONNECTION || $SSH_TTY ]]; then
    # commands go here
fi
```

If you want to execute it on the local machine, create a function wrapper around `ssh`. Something like the following should work:

```
ssh() {
    if command ssh "$@"; then
        # commands go here
    fi
}
```

That may be too simple for your needs, but you get the idea.

Comment: I needed the command to be executed on the local machine. Thanks for the suggestion. It works smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. If the `ssh` session is a login shell (instead of a remote command), `bash` will source `/etc/bash.logout` and `~/.bash_logout` when you exit the shell.

If you want to execute a remote command, then you can force `bash` to be a login shell. The `LocalCommand` could be similar to this:

```
bash -l -c /execute/some/command
```

From `man 1 bash`

```
-c string   If  the  -c  option  is  present, then commands are read from 
string.  If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to 
the positional parameters,  starting with $0.
-l   Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell 

When  a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the 
files ~/.bash_logout and /etc/bash.bash_logout, if the files exists.
```

Comment: Not if executing a remote command (If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.). However, reading the OP question closer, it appears he wants something to happen locally, so I think you answer is more appropriate.